# Manually Set Application.Caller in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to use a button1 to activate button2. The problem is that button2 has to use application.caller which defaults to the button origanally pressed (button1).

How do I set a new value for application.caller?

Here's the sample code:

Button1:

```
Sub ShowAttack()
'Change the color of the other buttons to the background color.

'Pressed button to lighter color.
ActiveSheet.Shapes("AttackButton").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 14277081

'Other buttons to darker colors.
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DefenseButton").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 12566463
ActiveSheet.Shapes("SpellButton").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 12566463

'Toggle Appropriate Cells to unhide
Dim button As Shape
Set button = ActiveSheet.Shapes("AttackButton")
rw = button.TopLeftCell.Row
Rows((rw + 4) & ":" & (rw + 74)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Hide appropriate cells within shown section

Set Application.Caller = ActiveSheet.Buttons("WeaponDetailsButton1").Name
Application.Run ActiveSheet.Buttons("WeaponDetailsButton1").OnAction

Range("AT51").Select

End Sub
```

Button 2:

```
Sub HideWeaponDetails()
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer, rw As Integer
    Dim sel01 As Integer, sel02 As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        cs = .Column
        rw = .Row
    End With

sel01 = rw + 4
sel02 = rw + 14

Rows(sel01 & ":" & sel02).Select
If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Range("A" & rw - 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Name = "WeaponDetailsButton" & Selection(1).Value
Range("AV47").Value = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Name

Range("A1").ClearOutline
```

End Sub

Comment: You can't set that value - move the main functionality from button2 into a separate sub which has a parameter to which you can pass the caller: now you can call that from either button 1 or button 2.  Would be easier to post sample code if your existing code was included here.

Comment: Sure. Put it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ShowAttack()

    '...do stufff

    HideWeaponDetails "WeaponDetailsButton1"

End Sub

Sub button2_click()
    'all this Sub does is call HideWeaponDetails
    HideWeaponDetails Application.Caller
End Sub


Sub HideWeaponDetails(TheCaller)
    'use TheCaller instead of Application.Caller
End Sub
```

...or pass the button itself as a parameter